# Inline C# Object Creation in F#

Tags: object, f#, initialization

I'm trying to interop with a C# library in some F# code. Consider the following C# as though it were the library I'm working with (or skip below to see the actual library I'm working with first):

```
public class Options
{
    public Options(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceBuilder
{
    public ServiceBuilder ApplyOptions(Options options)
    {
        //Apply Options in some way
        return this;
    }

    public TheService Build()
    {
        return new TheService();
    }
}

public class TheService
{
}
```

I'm then trying to create the service but keeping it fluent I have the following F# code:

```
//Valid Approach but not inlined :(
let options = Options("Test")
options.SomeProperty <- "SomeValue"

let theService = 
    ServiceBuilder()
        .ApplyOptions(options)
        .Build();
```

```
//Invalid Approach because SomeProperty is not virtual
let theService2 =
    ServiceBuilder()
        .ApplyOptions({
            new Options("Test2") with
                member _.SomeProperty = "SomeValue2"
        })
        .Build()
```

Is there some way for me to initialize the way I want to **inline** in F# where I try to create "theService2"? In C# I'd just use Object Intializers. F# Object Expressions are out because I don't have control of the class to make the property virtual.

For additional context in what my C# above is mocking, I'm specifically trying to create a Serilog Logger using the [Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch#elasticsearch-sinks) nuget package and do roughly the code below in F# (again, **inlined** if possible):

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200") ){
         AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
         AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv6
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F# you can also [assign values to properties at initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors#assigning-values-to-properties-at-initialization), so to create your `Options` instance in a single expression you can do the following:

```ml
Options("Test", SomeProperty="SomeValue")
```

Comment: D'oh! Not sure how I missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For direct translation from C# - property initializers are the way to go, as suggested in @rob.earwaker's answer.

However, note also that in F# *everything is an expression*. There are no "statements" like in C#, every piece of code has a result of some kind. And this also goes for "composite", so to say, pieces of code, such as `let` blocks. This means, even if you don't feel like using property initializers, you can still do the initialization inline:

```
let service =
  ServiceBuilder()
    .ApplyOptions(
      let o = Options("Test")
      o.SomeProperty <- "SomeValue"
      o
    )
    .Build()
```

Or using `let .. in` and a semicolon to put everything on the same line:

```
let service =
  ServiceBuilder()
    .WithOptions(let o = Options("Test") in o.SomeProperty <- "SomeValue"; o)
    .Build()
```

Unlike C#, this approach also works for factoring out initializations into reusable pieces:

```
let service =
  ServiceBuilder()
    .WithOptions(let o = Options("bar") in mutateSomeOptions(o); mutateOtherOptions(o); o)
    .Build()
```

Comment: This is fantastic and helped expand my understanding of F#. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: "every piece of code has a result of some kind": but sometimes that result is `unit`.